# Using the range and list method to construct lists

Tags: python, list, range

I have to do the following but I don't fully get it.

The exercise:
Let `n` be a tenfold bigger than 100. Construct only using the range-method and the concatenation-operator.
The list: `[n+10, n+5, n, .., 10, 5, 0, 0, -5, -10, .., -n+10, -n+5, -n]`

What im thinking is writing something like:
`list(range(n+10,0,-5)` to cover n+10 till 0 and have `list(range(0,-n,-5)` to cover the second 0 till -n.

But this is incorrect, the answer is list(range(n+10,-5,-5)) + list(range(0,-n-1,-5)) but I don't understand how I could come up with some of the variables.

Does anyone have a clue how this works?

Comment: The piece of information that you seems to be overlooking is that the `stop` parameter of the `range()` is excluded: `list(range(0, 4)) == [0, 1, 2, 3]`. That is why your solution would not work, but what you indicate as "the answer" does.

Comment: So instead of list(range(n+10,0,-5) i should do list(range(n+10,1,-5) to include 0?

Comment: actually on the other side, e.g. `-1` instead of `1`

Comment: @Mohd That is wrong, because `0` is there twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer skips the last value in the first component of the final list, because the range function does not include the stop value.

> [The] answer is `list(range(n+10,-5,-5)) + list(range(0,-n-1,-5))`

The former list is `[n + 10, n + 5, ..., 5, 0]` while the latter complements it (i.e. it is `[0, 5, ..., -n + 5, -n]`).

Comment: Do you now how the range method eventually gets rid of n?

Comment: Indeed, the range function iterates over these values subtracting 5 from the previous each time up to the point that it becomes 0.
Say `n = 100`, then first component of the final list is `[110, 105, 100, 95, ..., 15, 10, 5, 0]`

Comment: It's not carrying on, it stops evaluating at the stop value, which in this case is `-5`.

Comment: n= 100 has to do with the: Let n be a tenfold bigger than 100 restriction?

Comment: No, `n = 100` is an example, `n` can be any positive number that is divisible by 5, I believe. You can choose `n` to be a thousand.